# Validar una contraseña desde un archivo .txt java

Tags: java, condiciones

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de *Stacks* y el profesor me manda que antes de pedir cosas en la agenda que ponga una contraseña. He hecho una contraseña pero la misma se encuentra en un archivo `.txt`.

Hago un `FileReader` y un `while` para saber el contenido y lo guardo en una variable, pero cuando hago un `if equals` y le paso la variable que contiene la contraseña, es como que no sabe que esa variable dentro tiene la contraseña.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO code application logic here

    ServerSocket servidor = null;
    Socket sc = null;
    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;
    final int PUERTO = 5000;

    //Le pasamos al servidor el puerto que va a utilizar
    servidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
    System.out.println("Servidor Iniciado");

    //Cuando el Cliente se conecte al Servidor va a entrar en el While
    while(true) {
        //La sentencia accept se mantiene a la espera de algun cliente
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc = servidor.accept();

        System.out.println("Cliente Conectado!");

        in = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());

        //Leemos la contraseña del fichero PASS.TXT y la escribimos en la variable pass
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("pass.txt");
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String pass;

        //Le preguntamos al cliente que ponga la contraseña de la agenda
        String contraseña;
        System.out.println("Indicame la contaseña de Acceso a la Agenda: ");
        contraseña = Scan.next();
        while ((pass = bf.readLine())!=null) {;}
        if(contraseña.equals(pass)){
            String mensaje = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(mensaje);
            out.writeUTF("Hola Dede el servidor");
            sc.close();
            System.out.println("Cliente Desconectado!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Contraseña Incorrecta, Porfavor intentalo de nuevo mas tarde!");
        } 
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Una sugerencia, no uses caracteres latinos en nombres de variables. Es mejor **String password** o **String clave**. Saludos

Comment: Si no estoy equivocado al hacer un `while pass != null` continuas redefiniendo pass hasta que`bf.readLine()` devuelve `null` por lo que siempre llegaras a la siguiente linia con `pass=null`.

Comment: Como dice @MauricioContreras en la mayoría de lenguajes se recomienda no utilizar caracteres fuera del alfabeto inglés para nombrar variables, o incluso se prohiben. Sin embargo, en Java se especifica soporte unicode casi completo para ello (documentos JSR). Siempre y cuando los ficheros de código fuente estén codificados en unicode, es totalmente válido utilizar caracteres con tildes, eñes, chinos, japoneses, etcétera. Lo he probado en distintos sistemas (Windows, Linux, Mac) con el JDK de Orcle y OpenJDK.